# ArcGIS iOS SDK get point value from local raster at coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis

I have an iOS app that includes a raster image (tif file) in its bundle. I want to query this raster file and get the value at a specific longitude and latitude.

I've done a bunch of research into the ArcGIS iOS SDK but can't find a solution to this problem. I want to do the query locally, I can't make it a service on some server.

I feel like this should be possible, it seems rather simple, but I can't find anything. If I can't do it in ArcGIS is there another iOS SDK or other solution you can recommend?

Thanks in advance!